# How do I find the page number/number of pages in a document?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a new document based on a template and need to know when my insertion or append results in a new page in the final printed output is there any property/attribute eg number of pages that can be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've search this a lot in the past and I don't think there's any property or any other way to know page info.

The solution I use is to insert page breaks on my template or via the script, using my own knowledge of how my template works, i.e. how much space it takes as I iterate, etc.
And then I know which page I am by counting the page breaks.

Anyway, you could an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: @DavidF Thanks for opening the issue. I've starred it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get total number of pages:

```
function countPages() {
   var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs("application/pdf");
   var data = blob.getDataAsString();

   var re = /Pages\/Count (\d+)/g;
   var match;

   var pages = 0;

   while(match = re.exec(data)) {
      Logger.log("MATCH = " + match[1]);

      var value = parseInt(match[1]);

      if (value > pages) {
         pages = value;
      }
   }

   Logger.log("pages = " + pages);

   return pages; 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Just returns `pages = 0` for me

Comment: can you please explain the while condition.