# Compress PDF file in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, convertapi

How to compress a pdf file in a Google Script ?

I already use convertapi to merge pdf files, successfuly.
But I try, unsuccessfuly, to compress the final pdf file

Code OK for MERGE

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(idPDF1);
formData['Files[' + index + ']'] = file.getBlob();
index++;


var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'payload' : formData,
'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var global_pdf_name = nom_fichier + " - " + dateJour + ".pdf";
var response_glob = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://v2.convertapi.com/pdf/to/merge?Secret=XXXXXXXXXX', options);
if(response_glob.getResponseCode() == 200) {
var contentText = JSON.parse(response_glob.getContentText());
var blob_glob = Utilities.base64Decode(contentText.Files[0].FileData);
var link_fact = destination.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(blob_glob, 'application/pdf', global_pdf_name));
```

// Code NOK for COMPRESS

```
    var formDataC = {};
    var fileC = DriveApp.getFileById(id_mergepdf);
    formDataC['File'] = fileC;
    var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'data' : formDataC,
    'muteHttpExceptions': false,
    'processData': false
    };

    var global_pdf_compresse = nom_fichier + " - " + dateJour + ".pdf";
    var response_globC = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/compress?Secret=XXXXXX', options);
    if(response_globC.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    var contentTextC = JSON.parse(response_globC.getContentText());
    var blob_globC = Utilities.base64Decode(contentTextC.Files[0].FileData);
    var link_factC = destination.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(blob_globC, 'application/pdf', global_pdf_compresse));
```

// Error message in the trace

> [19-10-24 08:34:44:348 CEST]
>   UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/compress?Secret=XXXXXXX,
>   {processData=false, method=post, data={File=Relance clients Celtys -
>   24/10/2019 08:33:59.pdf}, muteHttpExceptions=false}]) [0,087 secondes]
>   [19-10-24 08:34:44:449 CEST] Échec de l'exécution du script : Échec de
>   la requête pour https://v2.convertapi. Code renvoyé : 400. Réponse
>   tronquée du serveur : {"Code":4000,"Message":"Parameter validation
>   error.","InvalidParameters":{"File":["File size must be greater than 0
>   bytes.","The File field is requ... (Utilisez l'option
>   muteHttpExceptions pour examiner la réponse entière.) (ligne 113,
>   fichier "Code") [durée totale d'exécution : 45,23 secondes]

Comment: You need to revoke your convertapi tokens now, you have posted them in your original question.

Comment: DriveApp.getFileById(id_mergepdf) result is URL or file data?

Answer (score 3):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var fileC = DriveApp.getFileById(id_mergepdf);
formDataC['File'] = fileC;
var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'data' : formDataC,
'muteHttpExceptions': false,
'processData': false
};
```

To:

```
var fileC = DriveApp.getFileById(id_mergepdf).getBlob(); // Modified
formDataC['File'] = fileC;
var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'payload' : formDataC, // Modified
};
```

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [PDF to COMPRESS API](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress)
- [Convert a gdoc into image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55111503/7108653)

  - This thread also uses ConvertAPI. So this sample script might be useful for you.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.