# google apps script problem doc to pdf conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf

I've been using this function for a while and it's never given me any problems.

```
function ConvertDocToPdfSameFolder(docId,doc_name) {
  //converti un doc en PDF suivant nouveau nom et emplacement
  var id_folder = DriveApp.getFileById(docId).getParents().next().getId();
  var docblob = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getAs('application/pdf');
  docblob.setName(doc_name + ".pdf");
  var desti_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id_folder);
  var pdf = desti_folder.createFile(docblob);
  var id_pdf = pdf.getId();
  return id_pdf;
}
```

I use this function to convert a doc to PDF.
The problem is that the size of the doc file is 4.9Mb and when converted the PDF is 28.5Mb. It's no longer possible to send this PDF by email.

If you have any ideas...

It worked before

Comment: While it's actually kinda charming you misspelled google in your title. Please be more careful with your title texts as they help to find relevant posts (SEO stuff ;)

Comment: I think I write the word Google 10 times a day...Thank you, that's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a downfall of converting any document (Google Docs, Word, etc.) to a PDF.

- When images are converted to the PDF document, they are encoded. This takes up a lot more space in the PDF. In the Google Doc, it just references the images stored on Googles servers.
- The PDF conversion stores all formatting details (fonts, colors, layout positions). This is so the PDF looks the same on all devices.
- Google Docs are designed extremely well for efficient storage, as this is in Google's best interest. PDFs prioritize preserving the exact visual representation of the original document which sacrifices some compression.

To solve your problem, I would recommend compressing your PDF after it is produced. Adobe has a free tool online to compress PDF files (https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/compress-pdf.html). You can also use Acrobat:

- Open your PDF in Adobe Acrobat.
- Go to File > Save As Other > Reduced Size PDF... (This option might be under the "Protect & Standardize" menu in older versions)
- Choose a compatibility setting (ideally, select the version compatible with the features in your PDF). Choosing a later version might result in greater compression, but ensure it opens correctly on other devices.
- Click OK. Acrobat will create a new and compressed PDF.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your reply.
When we think Google, we think automation. There are +/- 100 docs converted per day. There are 10% that cause problems. I'm not going to convert manually.

Again, it worked before, same document, same content type, same code. Something has changed, but what and what is the solution in automatic and not manual to reduce the size of PDFs.

Thanks

Comment: @Greg_apps_script Using the builtin `DocumentApp.openById(docId).getAs('application/pdf');` leaves us up to Googles implementation. You might want to try getting the blob of the file and using a PDF compression API to send and retrieve the file. Please take a look at this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58535537/compress-pdf-file-in-google-script