# How to convert PDF to image using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation

I am stuck converting PDF in Google Apps Script to any image format (jpg, png).

The use case is:

- the PDF is taken from email attachment
- needs to be converted to separate images per page (each page 1 image)
- these images needs to be saved to drive

Does someone has experience or example how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail your goal, for example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55111503

Comment: @Tanaike thanks it works and answers my question perfectly

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I flagged this question as the duplicated question.