# Problem sending data from a newly created PDF file to my website

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I create a PDF and then send its information to my website so that this PDF is converted to an image file and published:

```
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/' +
      'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
        '/export?format=pdf' +
          '&size=0' +
            '&portrait=true' +
              '&fitw=true' + 
                '&top_margin=0' +            
                  '&bottom_margin=0' +         
                    '&left_margin=0' +        
                      '&right_margin=0' +     
                        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                          '&pagenum=false' +
                            '&gridlines=false' +
                              '&fzr=FALSE' +
                                '&gid=' +
                                  'aaaaaaaaaaa';
    
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();
    
    //...get token and Blob (do not create the file);
    
    var fileName = ss.getSheetByName("General").getRange("H2").getValue();
    
    //Access or create the 'Archives' folder;
    var folder;
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Archives");
    if(folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    }else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Archives");
    }
    
    //Remove duplicate file with the same name;
    var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
    if(existing.hasNext()) {
      var duplicate = existing.next();
      if (duplicate.getOwner().getEmail() == Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
        var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
        var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
          method: 'delete',
          muteHttpExceptions: true,
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
        });
        var status = dres.getResponseCode();
        if (status >=400) {
          
        } else if (status == 204) {
          folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(fileName));
        }
      }
    } else {
      folder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(fileName));
    }
    
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    createPostByFileName(folder, fileName);
```

```
function createPostByFileName(folder, fileName) {
  var fileIterator = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if(fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = fileIterator.next()
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)
    name = file.getName();
    league = name.split(' ')[0];
    title = name.split(league)[1].split('.pdf')[0];
    link = file.getUrl();
    shareable = link.split('/view')[0];
    id = file.getId();
    var data = {
      'api_league_name': league,
      'title': title,
      'google_drive_id': id,
      'google_drive_url': shareable,
      'pass': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
    };
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.xxx.com.br/api/posts', options);
  }
}
```

For some reason I am forced to put `Utilities.sleep(5000);` before calling the function that sends the PDF data to my website, because if I don't, when the website tries to convert the PDF to an image, an problem happens as if the PDF is not yet available in the folder or it generates a big slowdown until can access the file.

Obviously putting this `sleep` is not a professional way to solve the case, because then I can't even know why this happens.

Anyone who has had this experience, can tell me how I should proceed in a professional way?

Comment: In your situation, for example, when the file is created by Drive API instead of DriveApp, is `Utilities.sleep(5000)` required to be used?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I've never had contact with the use via Drive API, I'll study about it to be able to convert this code to use it!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether using Drive API is the direct solution to your issue, I thought that it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Tanaike Do you know any way to convert a spreadsheet page into an image? It would also help me a lot if there is any way! I saw someone talking about saving as a PDF, then throwing that PDF into a Google Docs and converting it to an image there, but he didn't explain how.

Comment: About the conversion from PDF to image, is this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55152707 And, as another workaround, how about both creating and sharing a file using only Drive API? How about testing it?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm still struggling to convert DriveApp to Drive API, I believe that in a few days I'll learn how to use it and I'll do the tests, thanks for indicating the answer URL, it was useful for learning!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you wait for it? I would like to modify your script using Drive API.

Comment: @Tanaike If you want to do it, I would thank you, it would be very useful for me and would help me to test it and see if it works.

Comment: @Tanaike Do you want me to create a question about how to convert this code from DriveApp to Drive API?

Comment: I prepared a modified script using Drive API. In this modification, your 2 functions are merged into one function. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussions in the comment, when Drive API is used for your script, it becomes as follows. Before you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sample() {
  const createFile = (filename, blob, folderId) => Drive.Files.insert({ title: filename, parents: [{ id: folderId }] }, blob);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/' +
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' +
      '/export?format=pdf' +
        '&size=0' +
          '&portrait=true' +
            '&fitw=true' + 
              '&top_margin=0' +            
                '&bottom_margin=0' +         
                  '&left_margin=0' +        
                    '&right_margin=0' +     
                      '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                        '&pagenum=false' +
                          '&gridlines=false' +
                            '&fzr=FALSE' +
                              '&gid=' +
                                'aaaaaaaaaaa';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token } });
  var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();
  var fileName = ss.getSheetByName("General").getRange("H2").getValue();
  var folder;
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Archives");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Archives");
  }
  var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var pdfFileId = "";
  if (existing.hasNext()) {
    var duplicate = existing.next();
    if (duplicate.getOwner().getEmail() == Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
      var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + duplicate.getId();
      var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl, {
        method: 'delete',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
      });
      var status = dres.getResponseCode();
      if (status >= 400) {
      } else if (status == 204) {
        var obj = createFile(fileName, pdfBlob, folder.getId());
        pdfFileId = obj.id;
      }
    }
  } else {
    var obj = createFile(fileName, pdfBlob, folder.getId());
    pdfFileId = obj.id;
  }

  // Utilities.sleep(5000);

  Drive.Permissions.insert({ role: "reader", type: "anyone" }, pdfFileId);
  league = fileName.split(' ')[0];
  title = fileName.split(league)[1].split('.pdf')[0];
  shareable = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + pdfFileId;
  id = pdfFileId;
  var data = {
    'api_league_name': league,
    'title': title,
    'google_drive_id': id,
    'google_drive_url': shareable,
    'pass': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.xxx.com.br/api/posts', options);
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a sample script for testing whether `Utilities.sleep(5000)` can be removed.

Comment: I've activated it for testing and I'll leave it working in the next few hours and see the result!

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replying. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it worked! Now it is no longer necessary to add the 5 seconds of sleep. Do you have any thesis on why DriveApp happens this problem and with Drive API it doesn't?

Comment: @Digital Farmer Thank you for replyng and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Do you have any thesis on why DriveApp happens this problem and with Drive API it doesn't?`. Unfortunately, I have no it. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill. I think that I have to study more. I would be grateful if you can forgive my very poor skill.