# OCR Read a column from a PDF table in Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr

Here's a very accurate illustration of the PDF I'm dealing with, made with a very professional art program that is NOT paint:

[image: A document illustration. It's a paper beginning with one big square text box at the top, with three smaller boxes under it, spread horizontally. The first displays "a, b, c", each letter vertically, the second displays "a, space, b", and the third "a, c, space".]

I need to read the values "a, b, c".

The problem is that Google's OCR reads text horizontally, and the values end up all mixed together, as such: "a, a, a, b, c, c, b".

Here's my current code:

```
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob()

var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
}

var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, options)
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id)
var text = doc.getBody().getText()
```

Is there anything I can use to only read the values in the table/read words vertically? I don't know how to teach computers to read

Comment: I'm assuming your code takes a pdf and converts to Google Doc?  What do you see when you open the Google Doc, an image embedded in a page?  If so how is an App Script supposed to know that the image represents a table? And even if it were a table with an image in each cell, how is OCR supposed to recognize the vertical gaps in each cell?  I think you are asking for too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Apps Script library [ImgApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp).

First, download the pdf:

```
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob()
```

Then I used a function taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340090/19609795) to convert that pdf blob into an array of png blobs (one for each page):

```
async function convertPDFToPNG(blob) {
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText())
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) { // Overwrite setTimeout with Google Apps Script.
    Utilities.sleep(t)
    return f()
  }
  const data = new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes())
  const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data)
  const pageLength = pdfData.getPageCount()
  console.log(`Total pages: ${pageLength}`)
  const obj = { imageBlobs: [], fileIds: [] }
  for (let i = 0; i < pageLength; i++) {
    console.log(`Processing page: ${i + 1}`)
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create()
    const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [i])
    pdfDoc.addPage(page)
    const bytes = await pdfDoc.save()
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, `sample${i + 1}.pdf`)
    const id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId()
    Utilities.sleep(3000)
    const link = Drive.Files.get(id, { fields: "thumbnailLink" }).thumbnailLink
    if (!link) {
      throw new Error("In this case, please increase the value of 3000 in Utilities.sleep(3000), and test it again.")
    }
    var splitLink = link.split("=")[0] + "=s5000"
    const imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(splitLink).getBlob().setName(`page${i + 1}.png`)
    imageBlob.setContentType(MimeType.PNG)
    obj.imageBlobs.push(imageBlob)
    obj.fileIds.push(id)
  }
  obj.fileIds.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true))
  return obj.imageBlobs
}
```

After that, add a delay of 1 second, then create an object used to crop a page in ImgApp (you can read how the parameters work in the [github](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp) readme):

```
var pngs = await convertPDFToPNG(pdfBlob)
Utilities.sleep(1000)
const object = {
  blob: pngs[0],
  unit: "pixel",
  crop: { t: 100, b: 0, l: 0, r: 200 },
  outputWidth: 1600,
}
```

**Note: outputWidth limit is currently 1600 because it's the [largest thumbnail provided by the Slide API](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail#thumbnailsize). Trying to increase it may make the quality worse, by experience.**

The goal is to crop the image so that only the column you want is left. Experiment with different values in `crop: { t: 0, b: 0, l: 0, r: 0 }` until you get what you want.

Then, run the ImgApp.editImage() function and run OCR on the cropped image:

```
const croppedBlob = ImgApp.editImage(object)
var resource = {
  title: croppedBlob.getName(),
  mimeType: croppedBlob.getContentType()
}
var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, croppedBlob, options)
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id)
var text = doc.getBody().getText()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are applications that would see not in terms of humans (top to bottom) but in terms of left to right, though one could argue they are working right to left too.

Here is one with your desired methodology, but it's much cheaper to DIY, so I would simply set those vertical boxes as 3 lines of pdftotxt and output to 3 files, or one file as 3 sets.

[image]

You could try suggestions like use rotated word art (similar to MS Word art) to enforce vertical text blocks see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3554293/how-do-i-change-the-text-direction-in-google-docs-from-horizontal-to-vertical?hl=en

[image]