# Send Google Sheet TAB as an IMAGE in an EMAIL BODY

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to change the below google sheet app script so that a specific tab (sheet) is sent as an IMAGE in the email body.

```
function sendSheetTab() {
  var sheetName = 'sheetname'
  var destinationEmail = 'name@domain.com'

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)

  var params = ss.getId() + "/export?gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + "&format=pdf"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params

  var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
          "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , options)
  var contents = result.getContent()

  var subject = sheetName
  
  var body ='Please find attached yesterday apps performance.'
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(destinationEmail, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]})
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Just to be clear... do you want to send `sheetName + ".pdf"` as an image? This topic (sending images in HTML email) is quite popular, would you please summarise your research and any attempts that you have made to resolve this issue yourself.

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: In your showing script, one of the sheets in Google Spreadsheet is converted to PDF data. In this case, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55152707 In this thread, all pages in PDF data are converted to PNG images. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: yes @Tedinoz. this is what i'd like to do and have the image in the body of the email.. not as an attachment... i've not found anything that covers this yet?

Comment: `i've not found anything that covers this yet?`  Let's clarify:. There are two steps: 1= convert the sheet to an image (whether or not it is converted as sheet=> png, or sheet => pdf => png) and 2 = send email with inline image. Step#1 is covered by @Tanaike. Step#2 - what research have you done on this?